# What is a disputed flag?

Tags: support

Marco Ceppi just told me that moderators can't dispute flags, and I would like to know who can and what is it for?

If moderators can't use it who can?

for an example [I](https://askubuntu.com/users/flag-weight/10698) have 8 disputed flags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A disputed flag is when a 10K user marks the flag as invalid. When this occurs no one's flag weight is changed or modified.