# What happens when I vote to delete an answer?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

Does it go to the Low Quality review or not?

This is related to flagging questions. For high rep user maybe VTD is a better option.

Comment: That is not good. It could be a perfect option for high-rep users to delete poor answers not taking mods time to review flags. One delete vote is unlikely to be noticed without getting into a queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you vote to delete a post, it gets added to this [queue](https://askubuntu.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today) that I am sure no one uses anymore.

Comment: I know this place. It is not a queue. It is unlikely that someone looks there. IMO it is not good. Delete votes should be queued in the LQ.

Comment: As you know, I am looking for a way to delete LQ and NAA without involving moderators to save their time.

Comment: There are problems with having a delete queue though.. there are instances when people mindlessly press buttons hoping things go away without applying themselves.

Comment: Delete votes are available only to 10k+ users. It is unlikely that they mindlessly press buttons, like in raising flags. It requires 6 votes to delete for 3k+ users or 3 votes of 10k+ users to really delete. It is sufficient I think. And flagging does the same thing, but creates a huge queue for the mods.

Comment: Let's just say we (read: mods) have seen things.

Comment: Well, that is not obvious. You said that mods get too many flags to review. In many cases 10k+ users can help.

Comment: I was not correct. 20+ users can delete directly.

Comment: 10k+ users can cast delete votes on questions and 20k+ on answers. But it still requires at least 3 of them to delete a post.

Comment: Besides, the post must meet some requirements for these high rep users to VTD. I am sure you have already read [these](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

Comment: 1 downvote is enough to meet the criteria in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

When it gets required number of votes, it gets deleted. The required number is 3. Unless that answer is yours, in which case it will be deleted with just 1 vote of you.

Comment: I know that. The question is if it gets into review to get these votes.

Comment: Yes, it goes into the review queue

Comment: Are you sure? If you really know that, then this is the answer that I needed.

Comment: @Pilot6 As a privileged user, you can vote to delete certain posts which are considered Low Quality either because of flagging or the system's algorithm. Then if you vote it to delete, it still needs 2 more VTD from trusted users or 6 recommend deletion votes from other users. Also these low quality posts stay in review queue, so that they can gain recommended # of votes or dequeued . [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/188988), [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145292/188988) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/188988)

Comment: I can VTD any answer that has a negative score. So instead of flagging as NAA, I can downvote and VTD. The question is if the answer gets into the LQ queue.

Comment: ah! I understand now. If you VTD an answer (not in review queue) it may or may not be into the queue depending on whether system thinks it is of Low Quality. but if you delete _in the queue_, it will stay in the queue of other users